# Need Help on Oracle Select Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am finding difficulty to frame a select query.

PFB, for the table and corresponding data:

```
ID    DLS     MATCH_STATUS    LAST_UPDATE_TIME        BO      CH    FT
1      0         0              09-07-2013 00:00:00   IT      TE    NA
1      1         1              09-07-2013 00:01:01   IT      TE    NA
2      0         0              09-07-2013 10:00:00   IP      TE    NA
3      0         0              09-07-2013 11:00:00   IT      YT    NA
3      2         2              09-07-2013 11:01:00   IT      YT    NA
```

Here

```
Match_Status 0-->Initial Record
             1-->Singel Match
             2-->Multi Match
```

For every record there will be a initial entry with match_status 0 and subsequent matching process end other number such as 1,2 will be update.

I am trying to retrieve records such as total record , waiting match ,single match and multi match group by BO, CH and FT

Below is the expected out put:

```
BO   CH    FT  TOTAL_RECORD AWAITNG_MATCH   SINGLE_MATCH   MULTI_MATCH
IT   TE    NA   1              0               1             0
IP   TE    NA   1              1               0             0
IT   YT    NA   1              0               0             2
```

I have tried below query :

```
select BO,CH,FT,sum(case when match_status=0 then 1 else 0 end) as TOTAL_RECORD,
sum(case when match_status = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as AWAITING_MATCH,
sum(case when match_status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as SINGLE_MATCH,
sum(case when match_status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as MULTI_MATCH from
table1 where last_update_time >= current_timestamp-1
group by BO,CH,FT;
```

problem with the above query is, awaiting_match is getting populated same as total record as I understand because of match_status=0
Similarly  I tried with

```
select BO,CH,FT,sum(case when match_status=0 then 1 else 0 end) as TOTAL_RECORD,
select (sum(case when t1.ms=0 then 1 else 0 end) from
(select max(match_status) as ms from table1 where last_update_time >=  current_timestamp-1  group by id)t1) )awaiting_match,
sum(case when match_status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as SINGLE_MATCH,
sum(case when match_status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as MULTI_MATCH from
table1 where last_update_time >= current_timestamp-1
group by BO,CH,FT;
```

problem with the approach is awaiting_match is getting populated with the same value for subsequent row entry.

Please help me with a suitable query for the desired format.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Would you explain what does columns in expected output (`TOTAL_RECORD AWAITNG_MATCH   SINGLE_MATCH   MULTI_MATCH`) mean?

Comment: Its the count of record in each stage ..for example a record with id 1 inserted into the table then its initial status will be 0 in match status which is nothing but awaiting match, once matching process end , the subsequent insert will happen with the same record but different match status lets say 1 for single match. and so on...Total Record is nothing but distinct count of id , awaiting match is total count whose records currently in match status 0 and so on...point to be noted once matching process end and subsequent insert happened will known as latest stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want the *last* match status.  I am guessing that this is actually the maximum of the statuses.  If so, the following solves the problem by first grouping on `id` and then doing the grouping to summarize:

```
select BO, CH, FT,
       count(*) as TOTAL_RECORD,
       sum(case when lastms = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as AWAITING_MATCH,
       sum(case when lastms = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as SINGLE_MATCH,
       sum(case when lastms = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as MULTI_MATCH
from (select id, bo, ch, ft, MAX(match_status) as lastms
      from table1
      where last_update_time >= current_timestamp-1
      group by id, bo, ch, ft
     ) t
group by BO, CH, FT;
```

If you actually want the last update to provide the status for the `id`, then you can use `row_number()` to enumerate the rows for each id, order by update time descending, and choose the first one:

```
select BO, CH, FT,
       count(*) as TOTAL_RECORD,
       sum(case when lastms = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as AWAITING_MATCH,
       sum(case when lastms = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as SINGLE_MATCH,
       sum(case when lastms = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as MULTI_MATCH
from (select id, bo, ch, ft, match_status,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by last_update_time desc) as seqnum
      from table1
      where last_update_time >= current_timestamp-1
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
group by BO, CH, FT;
```